# Go: How to loop through files and compare ModTime to a date?

Tags: go

I'm trying to loop through files in a directory and compare their ModTime against a certain date in order to delete older files.

I'm using ioutil.ReadDir() to get the files but I'm stuck with how to retrieve the ModTime of each file.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The return from `ioutil.ReadDir` is `([]os.FileInfo, error)`.  You would simply iterate the `[]os.FileInfo` slice and inspect the `ModTime()` of each.  `ModTime()` returns a `time.Time` so you can compare in any way you see fit.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "time"
)

var cutoff = 1 * time.Hour

func main() {
    fileInfo, err := ioutil.ReadDir("/tmp")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    now := time.Now()
    for _, info := range fileInfo {
        if diff := now.Sub(info.ModTime()); diff > cutoff {
            fmt.Printf("Deleting %s which is %s old\n", info.Name(), diff)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Where can I find info about the return of ioutil.Readdir being ([]os.FileInfo, error)? I want to understand this concept instead of just using your answer without knowing the why.

Comment: Thanks again. Last question ( I hope) - I'm trying to delete the file in the if clause that meets the criteria but I'm struggling with what variable I use when calling os.Remove(). Any help is appreciated...
    for _, info := range fileInfo {
      if diff := now.Sub(info.ModTime()); diff > cutoff {
 fmt.Printf("Deleting %s\n", info.Name())
 os.Remove(??)

Comment: @Alfonso, you have the `info.Name()`, you have the directory, there is `path.Join`, and `os.Remove` takes a file path.  Seems like all the pieces are there an waiting.

Comment: I have it now. Thanks for all the help!